# View size is not correct while working on Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, resize, scale

I'm on CC 23.1.

Here's the "preview" when I'm working on Illustrator, Zoom 100%:

[image]

But once I export on SVG (and I open on other software, or browser Chrome), here's the result:

[image]

It's clearly scaled!!!

This means that I'm not working on how it will be rendered. 
And sometimes (especially when working with font) mess up the result once exported.

Why this? And how can I fix it?

Here's the export option:

[image]

Comment: What are the **measurements** of the files?

Comment: @Scott what do you mean?

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of the shape? Unless we have a size reference, we can't determine which one is correct.

Comment: 270x380 pixels (should be). But on illustrator is displayed bigger than 270x380, as you can see (even if Info window says 270x380px) :O

Comment: Illustrator's "view at 100%" is entirely dependent upon your monitor's *pixel destiny*. It's not a direct 1:1 thing, never has been. Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22496/illustrator-view-actual-size-smaller-than-life-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrator: View -> Actual Size smaller than life size](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22496/illustrator-view-actual-size-smaller-than-life-size)

Comment: @Scott: that's strange! My resolution is 1366x768 pixels, on a 15.6 inches. So 100.45 PPI. This means I should set a zoom of ~139.5%, which is "larger" than 100% (even more wrong). Sure about this? If I set a % of 72, it seems more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator leads a double-life being capable of creating both *print documents* measured in physical units and *web documents* measured in pixels. This creates some unexpected side effects.

By measuring your output file and looking at the ruler in the screenshot, I can see that you have created a document with the dimensions 270x380 px.

With ordinary preview a 270x380 px file is displayed as if it were a print document at 72 ppi with the physical dimensions 270x380 **points** (not pixels). A bit strange, but that's how it is. (You can create a print document with those settings to verify.)

To preview a web document at its correct pixel dimensions turn on ***View > Pixel Preview***.

Comment: Thats weird! How can I enterely work in pixels? I don't want points, all pixels! This way I really see on what I'm really working on...

Comment: Keep *Pixel Preview* turned on all the time.

Comment: Uhm, it doesnt "scale". When you zoom, it seems raster rather than vectorial. I think thats Just a preview, not a modality

Comment: But if you are creating a document where the exact pixel dimensions matter doesn't it just make sense that you see pixels when zooming in? If it "scaled" and showed sharp vectors at any scale you suddenly don't care about the actual pixels anymore. That's Illustrator's dilemma and probably one of the reasons why it behaves as it does.

Comment: Then turn off *Pixel Preview* when zooming in and only turn it on when you want to see the whole image at 100% scale.

Comment: But I'm making a scalable image (SVG), not PNG! I need it vectorized, for different zoom on my application. But at 100%, well, it should display 100% :)

Comment: Your artwork is still vectorized. It's just a preview. I'm sorry. Just trying to explain what's happening to my best knowledge. I *am* annoyed that Illustrator (and InDesign) mixes pixels and physical units, but I can't really see the big problem for your workflow.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to work on "real" artwork. This way, when I need to zoom, I always need to switch that Pixel preview on/off, else (once I zoom +), the whole looks very ugly (i.e. it looks not vectorized). Try set that option and than zoom 200%...

Comment: I'm just explaining it, I'm not defending it. I'm not affiliated with Adobe. Can you accept my answer as being correct even though you don't like it? 